# The complex layout of columns (for cheatsheet)

Tags: packages, multicol, tools

Objective: to A4 paper in four columns on two sides to print text. Requirements: 1) sheet is cut into the column (ie on both sides of the sheet of the border must be the same), and 2) the most difficult, the numbering of the columns after cutting must go in sequence (ie, quarters has an associated text).

Illustrative example. The original list, side A: | 1 | 2 | 3 | | 4 |, side B: | 5 | 6 | 7 | | 8 |. Printed: | 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | and | 8 | 6 | 4 | 2 |. After cutting, we have four quarters numbered columns | 1 | 2 |, | 3 | 4 | etc.

Did this through pstops, but the pdf shows only three columns.

[image]

Above is a screenshot PS_View. As a result, when converting to pdf using ps2pdf in the output file there is no lower "column", just an empty space.

What should I do to all 4 "columns" (page) displayed on the output sheet?

Page layout options in tex file:

```
\documentclass[6pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=74.25mm, paperheight=210mm, margin=1cm]{geometry}
```

The resulting input.ps and pdf looks as it should. Process it:

```
pstops -w74.25mm -h210mm -d1 8:6R(0h,0w)+4R(0h,1w)+2R(0h,2w)+0R(0h,3w),1R(0h,0w)+3R(0h,1w)+5R(0h,2w)+7R(0h,3w) input.ps maket.ps
```

.PS output is shown in the picture above.

**Update**

More low, in answers, @Tom has pushed on packet usage pdfpages. The task dares as follows. Beforehand generated pdf with the necessary page size it is processed by other tex-file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,
    landscape % sheet orientation
    ]{article}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdfset{
    nup=4x1 % 4 pages are allocated on one sheet as 4 columns in one row
    ,frame % to frame page with the frame
    }
\includepdf[pages={1,3,5,7}]{input.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={8,6,4,2}]{input.pdf}
...
\end{document}
```

Numbers in a `\includepdf` specify a sequence of pages on sheet. Further in a command numbering walks with 8.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Although an interesting TeX problem, I cannot help but condemn the practice using cheat sheets as opposed to studying for the exam.

Comment: @Martin: I doubt this is intended as an aid to cheating (it's a very brazen question if it is!) ["Cheat sheet" can also be used to just mean "handy reference"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheat_sheet#As_reference_cards)

Comment: @Tom Much as I'd like to agree, the line `\documentclass[6pt]{article}` kind of gives it away -- you don't usually make a "handy reference" with such a small font size. Some of my fellow students used the same technique to prepare cheat sheets, so I'm familiar with this layout.

Comment: @MartinTapankov: that's right, this cheatsheet to prepare for exams. I will not go into philosophical reasonings, but I suggest you think over a glass of tea. War - it's bad. But it is the stimulus of progress, which gave the benefit such as the Internet (the project's _military_ organization DARPA).

Comment: @MartinTapankov, don't jump to conclusions. I found this post useful as I'm preparing for an exam that allows one double-sided sheet of notes with any font size desired: i.e. an officially sanctioned cheatsheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why your `pstops` toolchain doesn't work, but as you want to end up with a PDF anyway, why not use [PDFjam](http://freshmeat.net/projects/pdfjam/)?

Something like

```
pdfjam --outfile maket.pdf --a4paper input.pdf 1,3,5,7,8,6,4,2
```

Comment: Thanks! This way has yielded the necessary result. To the decision of the described task has applied a packet pdfpages. Has added in a post the decision.